# animation completion called immediately

Tags: iphone, ipad, objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation

I have the following animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 
                 animations:^{ 
                     [childViewController_.view setAlpha:0];  
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [childViewController_.view removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

When performed as above, the completion block is called immediately.
If I don't have the completion block however, then the animation is performed as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**
The `finished` flag in the completion block is `NO`.

Comment: What is the function receiving for its finished parameter? Could something else be interrupting the animation?

Comment: You are right - it is returning NO.
How do I know the reason for this?

Comment: I've got the same problem, did you find a solution for this eventually?

Comment: NO could be returned if your animation was interrupted.

Comment: is it possible that your view get released?

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to check one condition

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 
                 animations:^{ 
                     [childViewController_.view setAlpha:0];  
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished)
                     {
                          [childViewController_.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }
                 }];
```